# Vue.js sometimes fails to load component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Nothing changed on a piece of code in production. But now I am getting reports that once in every couple of hundred times a template can not be loaded and the page crashes. I am working with vue 2.16.

The errors are:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #my-component-template
[Vue warn]: Template element not found or is empty: my-component-template
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

I have also noticed that the vue developer plugin shows and two root components. When it does not crash it only shows one.

Where can I start to debug this? Since it happens only seldomly it is hard to debug. The code base is quite large and old and not mine, but it was working (somehow) before. Could it because the server is too slow and some things are called asynchronously? The production server has been under more stress and things have slowed down.

Any tips or research directions appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by putting all my vue code into a

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // ...Vue code here.. 
});
```